# faster alternative to object.size?

Tags: r

Does there exist a faster way to identify an object size other than `object.size` (or a method to have it execute more quickly)?

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
object.size(DB.raw)
#  5361302280 bytes
Sys.time() - start.time
#  Time difference of 1.644485 mins  <~~~  A minute and a half simply
                                           to show the size

print.dims(DB.raw)
#  43,581,894 rows X 15 cols
```

I'm wondering also why it takes so long to compute the object size? Presumably for each column it has to traverse each row to find the total size for that column?

Comment: `system("ls -l DB.raw")` ?   (yeah I know the thing is currently in your environment and not necessarily a file).  Does it help if you try something like `object.size(unlist(DB.raw))` , or is it acceptable just to take   `prod(dim(DB.raw))*{number of bytes per element}` ?

Comment: Carl, the `unlist` option (with `use.names=FALSE`) is at 10+ minutes and still going, so I guess not, but good suggestion.  `system` as you mention, not really an option in this case

Comment: duh, I only have 8GB on this machine.  `DB.raw` is already 5+GB. If I `unlist` it then my poor little computer starts coughing

Answer (score 6):

On a Windows box, you might be able to get a pretty close estimate using `gc()` and `memory.size()` before and after creating `DB.raw`.

```
gc()
x <- memory.size()
# DB.raw created, extra variables rm'ed
gc()
memory.size() - x # estimate of DB.raw size in Mb
# object.size(DB.raw) / 1048576 # for comparison
```

Comment: unfortunately... `Warning message:
'memory.size()' is Windows-specific 
`

Comment: bummer. I'm going to leave the answer here in case it helps some Windows user in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason it is taking a long time is because you have character objects.  This seems to be because it needs to count the number of characters in order to determine the size, although I'm not sure.

```
x<-rep(paste0(letters[1:3],collapse=""),1e8)
system.time(object.size(x))
##  user  system elapsed 
## 1.608   0.592   2.202 
x<-rep(0.5,1e9)
system.time(object.size(x))
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.000   0.000   0.001
```

We can see longer strings taking up more space (at least in some cases) like this:

```
> x<-replicate(1e5,paste0(letters[sample(26,3)],collapse=""))
> x1<-replicate(1e5,paste0(letters[sample(26,2)],collapse=""))
> object.size(x)
1547544 bytes
> object.size(x1)
831240 bytes
```

I can't think of any way around this, if you need an exact size.  However, you can get a highly accurate estimate of the size by sampling a large number of rows and calling `object.size()` on the sample to get an estimate of the size per row, and then multiplying by the total number of rows you have.

For example:

```
estObjectSize<-function(x,n=1e5){
  length(x)*object.size(sample(x,n))/n
}
x0<-sapply(1:20,function(x) paste0(letters[1:x],collapse=""))
x<-x0[sample(20,1e8,T)]

> system.time(size<-object.size(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.632   0.856   2.495 
> system.time(estSize<-estObjectSize(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.012   0.000   0.013 
> size
800001184 bytes
> estSize
801184000 bytes
```

You have to tweak the code a bit to get it to work for a data frame, but this is the idea.

To add: it looks like the number of bytes per character to store an array of strings depends on a few things, including string interning and excess allocated buffer memory used during string construction.  It's certainly not as simple as multiplying by the number of strings, and it is not surprising that it should take longer:

```
> bytesPerString<-sapply(1:20,
+   function(x)
+       object.size(replicate(1e5,paste0(letters[sample(26,x)],collapse="")))/1e5)
> bytesPerString
 [1]  8.01288  8.31240 15.47928 49.87848 55.71144 55.98552 55.99848 64.00040
 [9] 64.00040 64.00040 64.00040 64.00040 64.00040 64.00040 64.00040 80.00040
[17] 80.00040 80.00040 80.00040 80.00040
> bytesPerChar<-(bytesPerString-8)/(1:20+1)
> bytesPerChar
 [1] 0.0064400 0.1041333 1.8698200 8.3756960 7.9519067 6.8550743 5.9998100
 [8] 6.2222667 5.6000400 5.0909455 4.6667000 4.3077231 4.0000286 3.7333600
[15] 3.5000250 4.2353176 4.0000222 3.7894947 3.6000200 3.4285905
```

Comment: I was going to say (as you have discovered) that I doubt it's the character columns that are at fault.  Part of what I am trying to measure is how much memory I am losing / gaining by converting columns from different classes, and displaying the object size takes just about the same time for the different conversions

Comment: Well, characters certainly take longer than numeric types.  See my latest edit.  It looks like in some cases the string length does affect the size of a character object.  I wonder if R tries to keep track of which strings are actually pointers to the same character array when calculating sizes like this.

Comment: @mrip yes, R has a global string pool, so computing the size of an vector is hard because it has to determine how many uniques it has. Compare `object.size("banana")` to `object.size(rep("banana", 1e6)) / 1e6`